# event scheduler with declare statement

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a event scheduler with declare statement in it?

i have been trying run this query without any success

```
create event dele on schedule
every 1 day 
do
begin
declare c int; 
select count(*) into c from purchased;
if(c > 5) 
delete from purchased limit 2
end if;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are missing `THEN` after `IF`. See manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

try this:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT dele
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c INT;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c
        FROM purchased;

        IF(c > 5)
        THEN
            DELETE FROM purchased LIMIT 2;
        END IF;
END |

delimiter ;
```